# How to combine two list in to one with two columns

Tags: python, csv

Two lists

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
y = ['s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

How do I combine these two results and dump these to a CSV file with two columns, I have tried using `zip(x,y)` but it removes some end objects of list `y`. Most of the solution provides for those cases where objects in `x` and `y` are equal, as you can see in my case that is not.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? What should be written to the second column for the rows where no `x` value is available?

Comment: @MartijnPieters am using python 2, I used zip(x,y) and saved it in an another file, and wrote that file to csv, which had all objects of x but only first 5 objects of y. last three was truncated in the process

Comment: `for row in (((val,x[i]) if i<len(x) else ("", val)) for i,val in enumerate(y)): print(row)`. The `len()` check might be slightly expensive though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.izip_longest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead, and tell it what to use for those missing columns; for a CSV file an empty string would work:

```
for row in izip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=''):
    # ...
```

Note that in Python 3, the `i` prefix was dropped from the function name.

If you are writing these to a CSV file, you can send the whole object to the `csv.writer.writerows()` function directly:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

with open(filename, 'wb') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    writer.writerows(izip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=''))
```